# How can I set floating number using jquery roundslider plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, floating, round-slider

I use jquery roundslider plugin http://roundsliderui.com/ but I can't set floating number. When I set a floating number plugin round the value, but I don't want this. How can I solve this?

```
$("#slider").roundSlider({
    sliderType: "min-range",
    value: 40
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/s5gpugjn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [roundSlider](http://roundsliderui.com/) having the [step](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html#step) property, based on this the slider increments or decrements the value. So if you want to allow floating number, then you can set the step value as "0.1", "0.01" or "0.001" based on how many decimals you want.

Check the below demo:

## [**`DEMO`**](https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/s5gpugjn/1034/)

Comment: Well spotted. Their documentation is terrible.